# How can I learn to play Hearthstone?

Tags: hearthstone

Is there a printable guide(pdf) or book for HearthStone - Heroes of Warcraft?

I want to learn how to play this game properly, so I don't want to browse the net for scraping guides. Book is always a best solution to most problems :)

For example I am interested in stuff like, which cards are good for paladin or shaman or whatever?

Or which set of cards are good for which hero, for example a set of murloc cards?

Something like that.

In more detail: I am not searching for some advanced advice how to play the game, I just want to know basic tips, much like the tips that are shown when you start a game. Am I clear?

What goes with what.

Comment: Are you asking for a rule book? Or like a FAQ on strategies for hearthstone? The latter isn't really a good topic of discussion as it would be an opinion based, varying list.

Comment: more like a rule book with tips for each hero. Something like that. I found a wiki page, so now I am searching how to print the complete wiki site for HS, http://hearthstone.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Pack

Comment: I think you are really asking, "Where can I learn about effective decks for each class?", since you seem to already know how to play the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are drafting in the arena, high level players have built lists of possible cards and split them into tiers, helping you decide which cards to take. This can also translate somewhat to Ranked and Casual play - the cards in the higher tiers in the Arena list are generally also similarly powerful in normal play. The only exceptions being cards that have specific synergies with other cards that elevate their usefulness. The guide I personally reference is AntiGrav1ty's list, which is here on Google docs: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AifXEOqTcGcLdFVvWk1GRjVJTHJUaTVLcGViR1RRTFE&gid=20

As for a list of decks, Hearthpwn has an excellent resource where users can upload their decks, and it shows you how expensive (in dust) each deck is as well as each card and its abilities. It allows others to rate the decks as well - treat this site similar to a recipe site and I think you can get some use out of it. http://www.hearthpwn.com/decks

Beyond that, just keep playing. It doesn't matter how many times you lose. The more you play the more familiar with cards you will be, and you'll begin to spot combos and synergies between cards (both with the ones you'll play, and the ones played against you).

Answer (score 2):

Before you can play against other players, Hearthstone makes you complete a series of 6 tutorial matches.

As the game is entirely digital (never sold in boxes, etc.) there are no official Blizzard materials regarding "How to Play". But then again, the game is free to play for anyone with a Battle.net account, so I think your best bet in this is to simply play through that initial tutorial. If the in-game tutorial doesn't cover everything you're looking for, please do come back and ask more questions here.

Comment: I already finished the tutorial games and reached level 20. I also crafted my own decks, and I used "suggest a card" feature but I end up usually with bad deck :) That is why I asked for a book or guide.

Comment: There are 380 cards or so, each game I get to see a new card :D and something new happens, really awesome game, well done Blizzard.http://www.hearthhead.com/cards

Comment: I'd suggest taking a loot at Hearthpwn.com and using their deck browser. Even if you don't have the cards to build the decks, look at the lists. These aren't always good decks, but you'll start to see what a cohesive deck looks like. Try to recognize the synergies.